# What are binary dependencies when it comes to using frameworks such as spring?

Tags: spring, dependencies

What are binary dependencies?

Background: I am trying to learn more about spring frameworks and am confused as what they mean by binary dependencies.

Comment: Context, please. Where did you read that?

Comment: In general, Binary dependencies mean all the dependent jar files for the framework.